# Is There Extra Biblical Evidence Of Jews Having Communities In Egypt In The 8th Century BCE?

Tags: isaiah, israel, egypt

The prophet Isaiah who according to Isaiah 1:1 was a prophet in the 8th century BCE and according to Isaiah 11, there were Jews already exiled in Egypt in his time period.

> Isaiah 11:11- And it shall come to pass in that day, that the Lord
> shall set his hand again the second time to recover the remnant of his
> people, which shall be left, from Assyria, and from Egypt, and from
> Pathros, and from Cush, and from Elam, and from Shinar, and from
> Hamath, and from the islands of the sea.
>
> 12 And he shall set up an ensign for the nations, and shall assemble
> the outcasts of Israel, and gather together the dispersed of Judah
> from the four corners of the earth.

I know of the Jewish Elephantine community which some sources say go back to the 5th century BC but there were other sources that claimed they go back as far as the 8th century BC but I couldn't find evidence of that extra biblically. I understand that there was a large population of Jews in Egypt especially by the time of Alexander The Great. However, my question is there specific extra biblical evidence of Jews in Egypt in the 8th century BCE or even in the 9th century BCE?

Comment: This is not a hermeneutics question and might be better migrated to either judaism se or an se related to history.

Answer (score 1):

In his *[*Histories*](https://www.livius.org/sources/content/tacitus/tacitus-on-the-jews/)* (5.2–4), the Roman historian Tacitus (56–117 AD/CE) repeats the prominent theories of Jewish origins in his day. He writes that the Jews were in Egypt (8th century) under the days of Pharaoh Uahkare Bocchoris (he ruled ruled 718-712):

> Most authorities, however, agree on the following account. The whole
> of Egypt was once plagued by a wasting disease which caused bodily
> disfigurement. So pharaoh Bocchorisnote went to the oracle of
> Hammonnote to ask for a cure, and was told to purify his kingdom by
> expelling the victims to other lands, as they lay under a divine
> curse. Thus a multitude of sufferers was rounded up, herded together,
> and abandoned in the wilderness. Here the exiles tearfully resigned
> themselves to their fate. But one of them, who was called Moses, urged
> his companions not to wait passively for help from god or man, for
> both had deserted them: they should trust to their own initiative and
> to whatever guidance first helped them to extricate themselves from
> their present plight. They agreed, and started off at random into the
> unknown...

Does folklore count for extra Biblical evidence? Did Tacitus confuse a story of pharaoh Bocchorisnote's interaction with the Jews of his day with the ancient story of Moses?

Answer (score 1):

Beginning from the time of the Exodus, that the [Egyptians used slaves](https://www.thetorah.com/article/what-we-know-about-slavery-in-egypt) for construction projects is almost certain but that these were Hebrew or Israelite slaves cannot be known from the archeological record. Josephus is one non-biblical source that [confirms the biblical account](http://penelope.uchicago.edu/josephus/ant-2.html), but he clearly depends on the Bible for his information here, so it should probably not be included as non-biblical.

More intriguing is Josephus' identification of the [Hyksos](https://www.haaretz.com/israel-news/2021-03-25/ty-article/were-hebrews-ever-slaves-in-ancient-egypt-yes/0000017f-f6ea-d47e-a37f-fffeebef0000) as Hebrews for this is truly non-biblical reference. The Hyksos were Semitic traders who came to Egypt around 1650 bce and eventually ruled the Lower Kingdom from the city of Avaris. It is conceivable that the story of Joseph rising to power is related to that of the Hyksos but it remains in the realm of speculation.

Another candidate for Hebrews in Egypt is the [Habiru](https://www.newworldencyclopedia.org/entry/Amarna_letters), mentioned especially in the Armana Letters. They were nomadic herders and warriors who conquered several Canaanite towns. The constituted a serious challenge to the Egyptian administration in Canaan but there is little evidence for a major presence of the Habiru in Egypt proper.

Some of the biblical descriptions of military encounters between Egypt and Judah/Israel find partial [confirmation in Egyptian sources](https://biblearchaeologyreport.com/2020/01/24/shishak-an-archaeological-biography/). It is therefore reasonable to presume that in addition to military confrontations the biblical reports of trade and diplomacy between the Israelites and the Egyptians have some historical basis if they are exaggerated, especially during the supposed [Golden Age of Solomon](https://www.newyorker.com/magazine/2020/06/29/in-search-of-king-davids-lost-empire). If so, there is reason to expect that Israelite enclaves in Egypt existed to support these activities during the period of the Kings. However, when such communities developed into major Israelite neighborhoods capable of supporting a temple is impossible to say.

Regarding Isaiah 11, it is not necessary to date this from the time of historical Isaiah. It could be from [Second Isaiah](https://yalebiblestudy.org/courses/second-isaiah/lessons/introduction-study-guide-3/), a product of the Babylonian Exile or slightly later. If so it conforms to what the Book of Jeremiah ch. 43 tells us: namely that many Jews of that time settled in Egypt, including Jeremiah himself.

---

A point about terminology: "Jews" did not exist as such until after the Babylonian exile. So the question should be either 'were there Hebrews' and/or 'were there Israelites' in Egypt in Egypt, etc.